# extract table from index.html objective-c

Tags: html, objective-c, parsing, stringbyevaluatingjavascr

the problem is the following:
I'm trying to get a table from html using "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString". The table itself is pulled in NSLog, but she does not want to appear in the UIWebView. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0],@"index.html"];

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]]];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView1
{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");

    html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.getElementsByClassName('bottomwideborder')[1].innerHTML;"];
    html1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>%@</body></html>", html];
    [webView loadHTMLString:html1 baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]]; //Here page does not refresh

    NSLog(@"%@", html1); //It's all displayed

   [webView stopLoading];
}
```

I think this page should be updated somehow, but I do not know how ((

Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a simple variable mis-naming error.

I see:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView1
```

while you're referring to everything within that function as "`webView`" (without the "`1`").

Also, make certain that your "`webView`" is not NULL and that it's what you're expecting it to be, since you're attempting to load it with the (apparently correctly parsed) "`html1`" code.

Comment: Then, I get an error - local declaration of "webView" hides instance variable

Comment: As a result, I was shown just index.html, but it is not updated. In NSLog output is what I need!

Comment: Ohhh, I see what you're trying to do (and UGH). Don't do this kind of double web view loading. Try a different approach: Instead of loading your HTML directly into a web view to begin with, load a "`NSString`" object (via something like [`[NSString initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:) and then parse your "table" out of that and load the parsed table HTML into your web view.

Comment: Oh, how can I pull the table out of NSString without using "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString"

Comment: It may be worthwhile for you to set up a separate question for this (otherwise we'll have a very long comment history on your question), but the two methods I would consider off the top of my head would be brute force parsing out of the table HTML, or maybe loading up an offscreen / invisible webview with the string and then running the method on that.